# Unable to call UIView from Class and cast though For loop

Tags: ios, swift, for-loop, uiview, casting

I have about a dozen `UIViews` that I want to add via a For loop cast. Currently setting it up and could not getting it working. Stepped back and tried to set it up for just a single `UIView`, and still no luck.

I get the error:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Any advice for what I am doing wrong would be appreciated:

**Code:**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var button: HamburgerButton! = nil
    var block1: shapeTestUI! = nil

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let block = createBlock(block1)
        self.view.addSubview(block)
    }

    func createBlock(blocks:UIView) -> UIView {
        let block = blocks as UIView
        block.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50)
        return block
    }
}
```

Comment: Where do you get the error? Which line?

Comment: @Fogmeister when he try to access block1 property ofc

Comment: @Fogmeister no, this is obvious from his code, sorry.

Comment: @Fogmeister sorry. The For loop was the initial attempt and my end goal. Now just a single UIView. The error is at `let block = createBlock(block1)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to init `block1` before you can pass it to `createBlock` since `blocks` function param isn't an optional :

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    block1 = shapeTestUI() //Or any init from your shapeTestUI model

    let block = createBlock(block1)
    self.view.addSubview(block)


}
```

Comment: Okay thanks. But how would that look like if I had multiple UIViews? How can I init them all in one go? or would I have to do them individually?

Comment: Again, end goal is implementing a For loop.

Comment: It depends, do you need to keep them as properties? If not, you better create a for loop in your `createBlock` func which init each block

Answer (score 1):

Initialise the view before accessing it.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

var button: HamburgerButton! = nil
var block1: shapeTestUI! = shapeTestUI()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let block = createBlock(block1)
    self.view.addSubview(block)
}

func createBlock(blocks:UIView) -> UIView {
    let block = blocks as UIView
    block.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50)
    return block
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create an Array of UIView, using [this Array initializer](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_Array_Structure/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/structctr/Array/s:FSacFT5countSi13repeatedValuex_GSax_)

init(count count: Int, repeatedValue repeatedValue: Element)

Answer (score 0):

You assigned nil to block1 object and directly pass it to method before initialize the object.
So Before passing block1 to methods first initialize it.